# How to group using exists

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the following table

```
personid talent
1        swim
2        play
1        play
1        swim
2        play
3        swim
3        swim
2        play
```

So person 1 can both swim and play. Person 2 can only play. Person 3 can only swim.

I need to get the following result

```
personid  talent
1        both
2        play
3        swim
```

How can I do this using `exists` ?

---

I tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT personid, 
CASE WHEN (EXISTS(
SELECT * FROM mytable
 -- I got stuck
```

---

PS : I have a long solution that works . . But i do not like it because it is long

```
SELECT DISTINCT dis2.personid , CASE WHEN talcount = 2 THEN 'both'
ELSE talent END AS talent 
FROM
(
SELECT personid , COUNT(talent) talcount
FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT personid , talent 
FROM my_table
) AS dis
GROUP BY personid
) dis2
JOIN my_table dis3
ON dis2.personid = dis3.personid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the WITH clause to achieve the same effect:

```
WITH
  DISTINCT_TALENTS(PERSONID, TALENT) AS 
    (SELECT DISTINCT PERSONID, TALENT
     FROM TALENTS)
SELECT DISTINCT PERSONID, TALENT
FROM
  (SELECT A.PERSONID,
   CASE WHEN TALENT_COUNT = 2 THEN 'BOTH' ELSE A.TALENT END
   FROM
     DISTINCT_TALENTS A
   INNER JOIN
     (SELECT PERSONID, COUNT(TALENT) TALENT_COUNT
      FROM DISTINCT_TALENTS
      GROUP BY PERSONID) B
   ON A.PERSONID = B.PERSONID)
```

First you create a virtual DISTINCT_TABLES table:

```
+------------------+
| personid  talent |
+------------------+
| 1        play    |
| 1        swim    |
| 2        play    |
| 3        swim    |
+------------------+
```

next you create a subquery b with the following

```
+------------------------+
| personid  talent_count |
+------------------------+
| 1        2             |
| 2        1             |
| 3        1             |
+------------------------+
```

you join with original DISTINCT_TALENTS to obtain

```
+----------+--------+--------------+
| personid | talent | talent_count |
+----------+--------+--------------+
|        1 | both   |            2 |
|        1 | both   |            2 |
|        2 | play   |            1 |
|        3 | swim   |            1 |
+----------+--------+--------------+
```

you take the distinct personid, talent to obtain the final result.

A solution similar to using exists is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PERSONID, TALENT
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT
      B.PERSONID,
      CASE
        WHEN A.TALENT IS NULL THEN 'swim'
        WHEN B.TALENT IS NULL THE 'play'
        ELSE 'both'
      END TALENT
    FROM
      TALENTS A
    FULL OUTER JOIN
      TALENTS B
    ON A.PERSONID = B.PERSONID
    AND A.TALENT='play'
    AND B.TALENT='swim'
)
```

And finally, also with the `EXISTS` function used like a lookup function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PERSONID, TALENT
FROM (
  SELECT A.PERSONID,
         CASE 
           WHEN A.TALENT = 'play' AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TALENTS B WHERE A.PERSONID = B.PERSONID AND B.TALENT = 'swim')
           THEN 'both'
           WHEN A.TALENT = 'swim' AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TALENTS B WHERE A.PERSONID = B.PERSONID AND B.TALENT = 'play')
           THEN 'both'
           ELSE 
           A.TALENT
         END TALENT
 FROM
 TALENTS A)
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for reply. I do have a similar solution. I have posted it . I used DISTINCT  , COUNT  . . . I was hoping to get a concise solution with `EXISTS`

Comment: Added a solution with something similar to exists: it can be written with exists, but it's really, really more convulated, if you want I can write it down

Comment: Thank you . Please add the `exists` solution

Comment: Here you go! It's even shorter, but I think it's not efficient as the others.

Answer (score 12):

Do you really need to use EXISTS?

```
SELECT
    personid,
    CASE 
       WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT talent) = 2 THEN 'both'
       ELSE MIN (talent)
    END
FROM talents
GROUP BY personid
```

Comment: This is a better solution _1